# AWS S3 Permission to put in specific folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I figured out how to only put in AWS s3 bucket with the policy below. I want to limit the put destination to a single directory of S3, but when I add on the path I get permission denied. Which added action do I need to allow?

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know I was doing wrong but the policy is now working as expected.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/path/to/folder/*"
}
]
}
```

The command to put it there is

```
aws s3 cp put-from-cli.test6 s3://BUCKET-NAME/path/to/folder/
```

Be sure to be using the correct credentials.